# Google Maps JavaScript API error: ProjectDeniedMapError

Tags: javascript

[image]

Google Maps JavaScript API error: ProjectDeniedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#project-denied-map-error

I encountered this problem, how can I solve it

Comment: Did you check the Google Cloud Console? https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Did you solved it? I am facing the same issue. Please lighten my way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your billing account is not activated, or the relevant api is not enabled for the project.